# Google Analytics BigQuery Export Short Date Range

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

One of my Google Analytics exports isn't going very far back in time, only 71 days. I ran a sum on totals.hits and it's returning 9,220,187 so it's nowhere near the 10 billion hits or 13 months of data rule. Any ideas on how I can go further back?

Thanks

Comment: As you are a Google Analytics premium customer - I'll recommend you to go through your support contacts, they will be able to explore the situation better than us.

Comment: I am not but the client is, perhaps I can go through them. Cheers